# javascript get inner object from function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a function in javascript

```
 var fn = function(){

   var obj = {result: true};

   return obj.result;    
};
```

I have access to the function, but I need to get the inner `obj`. Is there a way to do that?

---

EDIT: Thanks to the answers below, I have managed to come up with a solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz 's answer was the closest, so I marked it as the solution.

```
 var f2 = function fn(){

   fn.obj = {result: true};

   return fn.obj.result;    
};
```

A client of this function can use it like the following :-

`var myFunction = f2;`

The function must be called though, to access the inner variables

`myFunction();`

After that one can do the following.

`console.log(myfunction.obj);`

This seems to be working. I would, however like to know if this is a good practice.

Comment: Can you `return obj` or is the function being used as a module (with IIFE)? If that latter, then no, this is the JS equivalent of private access.

Comment: maybe it's a better option to as the question of good practice in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access `obj` when you make it public.

```
function fn() {
    fn.obj = { result: true };
    return fn.obj.result;
}
console.log(fn());
console.log(fn.obj.result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the inner object outside of the scope of the function.